# Have problems with intellij idea 12/13 in xml file

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

I have some problems with refactoring `*.xml` file.

When I try to edit Fail, IDE hangs and I remove the process through Task Manager.

Comment: If you know what to edit then edit on other tool.

Comment: I try to use notepad to edit but result  very hard to check because idea helps me

Comment: i work on windows 7 and my project size 800 mb

Comment: What is the size of the file you're trying to edit?

Comment: my xml file have 10 кб